# Unable to change win8 toast app icon

Tags: .net, windows-8, notifications, toast

I have created a standard toast notification for a Windows 8 desktop app. This is working correctly and showing the notification. However, I can't see to be able to customise it.

I have two issues - see image:

[image: toast image]

1. How do I change the background colour of the toast notification?
2. How do I change the app icon in the toast notification?

This is a windows 8 desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Foreground: You can set "Foreground text" in you app manifest to dark or light.

Background: This follows the "Background color" of the app manifest - and hence will be the same as the app's tile background.

For most of the apps I've worked on, it's enough to set the tile color according the UI spec - and then set the 'foreground text' to light or dark. You can surely override the light/dark themes if you want to too.